# Calculation of DNA sequences

Tags: java, bioinformatics

Could you tell me how I can calculate the DNA sequences by Java using Levenshtein algorithm

Comment: Need a little more information please. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: As a first-time user, it might be useful to check out some of the questions posted here for overall style, and read the faq at http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 3):

Since you did not tag it as homework, I see no need in writing this yourself. [Apache's StringUtils has it](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the algorithm from [the Wikipedia page on Levenshtein distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance):

```
 int LevenshteinDistance(char s[1..m], char t[1..n])
 {
   // d is a table with m+1 rows and n+1 columns
   declare int d[0..m, 0..n]

   for i from 0 to m
     d[i, 0] := i // deletion
   for j from 0 to n
     d[0, j] := j // insertion

   for j from 1 to n
   {
     for i from 1 to m
     {
       if s[i] = t[j] then 
         d[i, j] := d[i-1, j-1]
       else
         d[i, j] := minimum
                    (
                      d[i-1, j] + 1,  // deletion
                      d[i, j-1] + 1,  // insertion
                      d[i-1, j-1] + 1 // substitution
                    )
     }
   }

   return d[m, n]
 }
```

(I'm sure you can make java out of that with a little work.)

pass in your two DNA sequences as `s` and `t` and it will return the distance as an int.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're after. You can remove the `System.out.println` statements if you like. Note that if you leave them in, that the first row and columns are omitted from what is printed.

Verified against the [results on the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

```
public int getLevenshteinDistance(String a, String b)
{
    // d is a table with m+1 rows and n+1 columns
    char[] s = (a).toCharArray();
    char[] t = (b).toCharArray();
    System.out.println(a + " - " + b);
    int m = s.length;
    int n = t.length;
    int[][] d = new int[m + 1][n + 1];

    int i;
    int j;
    for(i = 0; i < (m + 1); i++)
    {
        d[i][0] = i; //deletion
    }

    for(j = 0; j < (n + 1); j++)
    {
        d[0][j] = j; //insertion
    }

    for (j = 1; j < (n + 1); j++)
    {
        for (i = 1; i < (m + 1); i++)
        {
            if (s[i-1] == t[j-1])
            {
                d[i][j] = d[i-1][j-1];
            }
            else
            {
                d[i][j] = Math.min((d[i-1][j] + 1), //deletion
                        (Math.min((d[i][j-1] + 1), //insertion
                        (d[i-1][j-1] + 1)))); //substitution
            }
            System.out.print(" [" + d[i][j] + "]");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    return d[m][n];
}
```

To test:

```
    String a = "Saturday";
    String b = "Sunday";
    int d = getLevenshteinDistance(a, b);
    System.out.println(d);
    a = "kitten";
    b = "sitting";
    d = getLevenshteinDistance(a, b);
    System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) for Levenshtein contains an algorithm and an explanation of the resulting matrix. Simply implement the algorithm as a method and return the last element in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/Paste the function from the [Levenshtein Distance Algorithm](http://www.merriampark.com/ldjava.htm) and use it like so:

```
 String a = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
 String b = "AAAAAAAAACTAAAAAAA";

 int d = getLevenshteinDistance(a,b);
 System.out.println(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just interested in calculating the variation between two DNA sequences you should use the [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) not the regular Levenshtein distance.

The wikipedia entry contains some sample code which you surely are able to map to java code.